# C++ Delete char**

Tags: c++, char, delete-operator, args

I know there have been many questions about this but I have tried everything and NOTHING seems to be working.

I have `char**` and when I try to delete it, I get exception thrown. When I do not delete it, an exception is thrown after the function returns.

I have a function similar to this:

```
void function(){
     int argc = 5; char** argv;
     argv[0] = "...";
     argv[1] = "...";
     //...
     Package package;
     package.ProcessCommandLineArgs(argc, argv); // this does NOT delete argv

     // THIS FAILS
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
         delete[] argv[i]; // <--- EXCEPTION HERE
     delete[] argv;
}
```

I have even tried using the function only with this:

```
void function(){
     int argc = 5; char** argv;
     argv[0] = "...";
     argv[1] = "...";
     //...

     // just declare argv and delete it also fails
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
         delete[] argv[i]; // <--- EXCEPTION HERE
     delete[] argv;
}
```

I cannot not use `char**` as I have 4 classes that use the same arguments in a chain of calls so I do not have the option to use `vector<string>`.

I would appreciate any help.
If you want to vote down, do it, but please give me an answer as I have been stumbling with this for hours.

Thanks.

EDIT: I see why this got down-voted and right now I would down-vote it if I had seen it asked on SO. I have since changed all my programs to convert arguments into `std::vector<std::string>`. If I attempt to delete this question I will be at risk of losing my ability to ask questions since this already has an answer.

Comment: You never allocate memory for `argv`...

Comment: Ok so where do you `new argv`?

Comment: What do those functions do with the `char**`? Chances are you can still use `std::vector`.

Comment: In my code I had it `argv = new char*` but it wasn't enough. @Evan's answer clarifies all of it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A version of your code that might work is something like this:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 256 // TODO: set to the size you need...
void function(){
     int argc = 5;
     char** argv = new char*[argc]; // allocate space for the array!
     for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
         argv[i] = new char[MAX_SIZE];  // allocate space for the array entry!
     }

     // TODO: bounds checking!!!
     strcpy(argv[0], "...");     // set the string to the "..."
     strcpy(argv[1], "...");     // same...



     // cleanup
     for(int i=0;i<argc;i++) 
         delete[] argv[i];
     delete[] argv;
}
```

In short, only `delete[]` what you `new[]`, only `delete` what you `new` and only `free` what you `malloc/calloc/realloc`.

That being said, if you have control over the implementation of `ProcessCommandLineArgs`, it would be **far** superior to just pass a `std::vector<std::string>` and just not worry about the memory management.

Comment: You, sir, have my full respect. You have provided me with the full example for this unlike anywhere else. You clarified everything needed done. I only had to change `strcpy` to `strcpy_s` and everything is now working
I wanted to use `vector<string>` but I would need to change around 10 files to make it work because I have a set of programs that I originally designed to take input args from main.
THANK YOU.

Comment: I seriously cannot thank you enough. I have a deadline due and this was really killing me. The funny part is that the rest of my program is x1000 times more complicated but in that I was avoiding memory management as far as I can. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @Everyone, no problem. pointers and manual memory management can get rough, sometimes you just need a prod in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a surprise; you cannot `delete[]` something that you did not `new[]`!

In fact, your entire program has undefined behaviour, because your `char**` is uninitialised and doesn't point anywhere.

Those elements, if they were valid, point to string literals, which again cannot be `delete[]`d.